# How to eliminate tabbed column csv file in Java

Tags: java, csv

I need delete the word "Close" , that separated by tab at the end of first row using java. The rest of the file should remain unchanged.
how can i do this ?

["Close" is tabbed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi4m6.png)

I'm trying to adapt this code:

```
 public class removezero{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //scanner to read csv file
    Scanner replace = new Scanner(new    File("csvfile"));


    //array of string
     String [][] all= new String [10][10];

    //new csv file to write answer
    FileWriter removezero = new FileWriter(createReplacedCsv());

    int i=0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

     //write csv to array




    while (replace.hasNext()) {

                String[] result = replace.nextLine().split(",");

                all[i]= result;
                i++;


    }


       // write from  array to builder

    for(int j=0;j<5; j++){
        for(int k=0;k<5; k++)
            if(!(all[1][k]).equals("0")){builder.append(all[j][k]).append(",");}
            builder.deleteCharAt(builder.lastIndexOf(","));
            builder.append("\n");
    }


     //write to csv file
      removezero.write(builder.toString());
      removezero.flush();
      removezero.close();

     }




private static File createReplacedCsv() throws Exception {
    File replacedCsv = new File("removedzero.csv");
    replacedCsv.createNewFile();
    return replacedCsv;
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Say you define:

```
private static String removeTabbedColumn(String line) {
    int indexOfTab = line.indexOf('\t');
    if (indexOfTab == -1) {
        return line;
    } else {
        return line.substring(0, indexOfTab);
    }
}
```

Now you can use

```
String[] result = removeTabbedColumn(replace.nextLine()).split(",");
```

I haven’t tested.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a CsvParser, for instance
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

```
final CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader());
try {
    for (final CSVRecord record : parser) {
        final String string = record.get("SomeColumn");
       // Get the intended columns here.
    }
```